# Uncaught Handler error.

Tags: android, android-handler

I am trying to do a HTTP Post and as I came to know that time consuming tasks should be used within a Async Task or a Handler, I tried to code it using a Handler but I am getting an Handler uncaught exception, Unable to determine where I am going wrong.  Below is my code and the log trace.

```
           @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button Bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button Btx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);




    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    etp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading", "Please Wait...");

            h = new Handler(){

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    dialog.dismiss(); 
                }
            };


            new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();

                    Connection();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        h.sendEmptyMessage(0); 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }.start();

        }
    });










   // Btx.setOnClickListener(Sig);




}





    private View.OnClickListener Sig =new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){


            Intent Sign = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Signup.class);
            startActivity(Sign);

        }
        };









    public  void Connection(){
    String is = null;
    String X = et.getText().toString();
    String Y = etp.getText().toString();

    if(X.length()>0 && Y.length()>0){
        A = X;
        B = Y; 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://animsinc.com/query.php"); 
        try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", X));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",Y));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //   et.setText(""); // clear text box
        //   etp.setText(""); // clear text box

        HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
        is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
       // in = entity.getContent();
      //  Log.e("post responce----->", "" + is);
        Toast.makeText(this,""+is, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }




    } else{
            // display message if text fields are empty
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    if(is != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,""+is, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

}

This is my Log Cat:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare logcat is just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are calling:

```
Toast.makeText(this,""+is, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

from worker Thread inside run() method. You shouldn't do it. You can manipulate with UI only from Main(UI) Thread.

**Solution** is to use [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or show Toast in Handler.